# Declaring mysql cursor error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, cursor

Background: I have a table with tons of entries that I need to traverse. Currently I'm doing this in my Django application, but it takes up way too much memory and takes a very long time.

Here's what I'm trying to execute on the database:

```
DECLARE gigantic_cursor BINARY CURSOR 
                FOR SELECT * FROM my_table
```

When I open a connection from my Python project and then call this, I get a SQL syntax error. Same error if I execute directly in the database with BEGIN..END blocks.

Python code just looks like:

```
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("DECLARE gigantic_cursor BINARY CURSOR 
                FOR SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

EDIT:
Put the declaration inside a stored procedure as follows:

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCursor()
-> BEGIN
-> DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM my_table;
-> END//
```

Python is now

```
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("exec CreateCursor()")
```

Now throwing `*** ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exec CreateCursor()' at line 1")`

Comment: and the error message is...? I'm guessing syntax error on `binary`, which you'll note is not available: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, full error message is:
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE c1 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM my_table END' at line 1`



I get the same thing if I remove `BINARY`

Comment: cursors can only be declared inside a stored procedure. a "naked" cursor isn't allowed.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, definitely feel like I'm getting close. Updated question

Comment: `cursor.execute("CALL CreateCursor()")` returns 0 and running `cursor.execute("FETCH 100 FROM c1")` gives me the same error as above.